# SQL Error with a simple Query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Im building an application but then learned we needed to use sql database and im getting this returned now and unsure why?

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM User WHERE (username = 'james' OR email = 'james') AND password =
'M4erz2BE/N7NYyE40UJRo5W1E1ZiqKpOMWQhm+R8Esc='
```

Comment: you may need to use bracket like [User].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're querying the correct database and that the [User] table is defined in the default schema. Else you'll need to explicitly specify the schema before the table name.

Also when you use identifiers (Column, table or database names) adjust yourself to surrounding those with brackets. It makes the query more readable:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE ([username] = 'james' OR [email] = 'james') AND [password] =
'M4erz2BE/N7NYyE40UJRo5W1E1ZiqKpOMWQhm+R8Esc='
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using the wrong database.  Either specify the database name in your connection string, or fully qualify your table name.

Also, "User" is a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186738.aspx). Change your query to this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourDatabaseName.dbo.[User] WHERE (username = 'james' OR email = 'james') AND password = 'M4erz2BE/N7NYyE40UJRo5W1E1ZiqKpOMWQhm+R8Esc='
```

Comment: Just gave that a go but its returning the same thing for some reason... ]Invalid object name 'User'. with query: "SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE (username = 'james' OR email = 'james') AND password = 'M4erz2BE/N7NYyE40UJRo5W1E1ZiqKpOMWQhm+R8Esc='"

Comment: edited.  Your connection string is likely wrong, or you may just not have access to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to select user, not sure but give it a try

```
      SELECT user 
      WHERE username = 'james' OR email = 'james'
      AND password ='M4erz2BE/N7NYyE40UJRo5W1E1ZiqKpOMWQhm+R8Esc='
```